# How to call functions properly in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I found this recursive Fibonacci assembly code on the internet and I was trying to improve this so the result would be printed out. thing is, if I add _main function and simply put

```
call _fibo
```

in there, the program will crash (not to mention adding more code). I think the caller has to clean up the arguments and what not, but in my mind it should work if there is no further code to be executed. Any pointers?

```
_fibo:
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
sub  esp, 16    ; ...AA-A-A-ND we've built the stack frame

mov  eax, [ebp+8]
cmp  eax, 2
jae  .recur

xor  edx, edx
jmp  .done

.recur:
sub  eax, 2
push eax            ; compute fib(n-2)
call _fibo
mov  [ebp-8], eax   ; save returned value in 8-byte local variable...
mov  [ebp-4], edx   ; ...in Little-Endian byte order.

mov  eax, [ebp+8]   ; get argument again
dec  eax
push eax            ; compute fib(n-1)
call _fibo
mov  [ebp-16], eax  ; save returned value in 8-byte local variable...
mov  [ebp-12], edx  ; ...in Little-Endian byte order.

; the next steps are not as efficient as they could be...
mov  eax, [ebp-8]
mov  edx, [ebp-4]   ; retrieve 1st computed value
add  eax, [ebp-16]
adc  edx, [ebp-12]  ; add 2nd computed value
.done:
mov  esp, ebp
pop  ebp
ret
;----------------------------------------------------------------
```

http://montcs.bloomu.edu/Code/Asm.and.C/Asm.Nasm/fibonacci.shtml

Comment: Just to learn the basics of it, surely it isn't meant for writing programs that could be split up into parts

Comment: The code does not seem 'C' to me, are you sure it is C language???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to write `main` in C, compile both parts separately, and link them into one executable. Here's an example for Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern long __attribute__((cdecl)) _fibo(int n);

int main()
{
        int number = 10;
        long result = _fibo(number);
        printf("%ld\n", result);
        return 0;
}
```

**Note:** from the top of my head, in Windows you should call `fibo` without underscore; and `__attribute__((cdecl))` would have to be `__cdecl`.

Add this line to `fibo.asm` to expose `_fibo` to `main`:

```
global _fibo
```

Compile/link the two modules with:

```
nasm -f elf fibo.asm
gcc main.c fibo.o
```

If you insist on writing `main` in assembly, you will have to learn about [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), as you probably have guessed already from keshlam's answer. To get you started, `_fibo` uses **cdecl**. You may find some very useful code samples here: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmexamples/

Comment: I knew about cdecl, but obviously need to learn more. Thanks, I'll try to fix it and let you know how i did :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the calling conventions right, then yes, "it should work." But those calling conventions include the argument to the function.  And presumably you want to actually do something with the result

Look at `.recur` for an illustration of how to set up the argument (in `eax`), call the function, and obtain the result (which was left on the stack, and in this case is being pulled back into `eax` and `edx`).

Then presumably you'll want to print out that result before exiting....